# why aria-checked attribute got disappeared

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, angular-material

"aria-checked" attribute got disappeared after deployment, while it was existing when testing.

I was expecting aria-checked attribute to exist for the  element. The same issue is in Firefox and Chrome. Kindly advise. My intention here is to know if the checkbox is checked or not and based on it, need to check it or uncheck based on some other conditions. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: writing code for understanding-- 
for(let i=3;i<14;i++){ 
 let checkboxElement = document.getElementById('mat-mdc-checkbox-'+i); 
 let inputElement =document.getElementById('mat-mdc-checkbox-'+i+'-input'); 
 if(checkboxElement!==null && inputElement!==null){
  array[i].element=inputElement;
  array[i].status=inputElement.getAttribute('aria-checked');
 }}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, they changed the logic behind the scenes. You can however, use `mat-checkbox-checked` class name on the `<mat-checkbox>` component, to find out if it is checked or not, like so:
`htmlElement.classList.contains('mat-checkbox-checked')`